# How to count strings within a specified date range in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with over 200k rows. I have been able to count the unique value of strings per Date AND Category combination. The dates are basically by months (01/01/2022, 02/01/2022, 03/01/2022, etc) and I have about 30 categories. I have another column called "start_date" which is dependent on the date for that row.

Sample Data:

`Date <- c("01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022", "05-01-2022", "01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022", "05-01-2022")`

`Category <- c( "A", "A", "A", "A","A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")`

`start_date <- c("06-01-2021", "07-01,2021", "09-01-2021", "09-01-2021", "10-01-2021", "01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "05-01-2020")`

`strings <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj")`

`df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Date, Category, start_date, strings))`

The difference in Date and "start date" varies with each category. I would like to know if there is a way to count the number of strings within a specified date range? I've looked into lubridate, zoo, runner, slider, etc. I've been looking at rolling sum too, but nothing seems to work because the "window size" varies by each category.

The code below is able to count the strings in each month per category, but would like to specify within a date range. I would like to stick with dplyr, lubridate, tidyverse, but open to all suggestions.

`df %>% group_by(Date, Category) %>% mutate(n_distinct(string))`

Comment: Please include a representative sample of your data `df` as text/code. E.g. use `dput(head(df, n = 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

To filter a specific range of `Date`s, we can use dplyr::filter():

```
df %>%
  filter(lubridate::mdy(Date) >= lubridate::mdy("02-01-2022") &
         lubridate::mdy(Date) <= lubridate::mdy('05-01-2022')) %>%
  group_by(Date, Category) %>%
  mutate(n_distinct(string))
```

Since both the dates in your dataframe ánd the date I put to compare with are character strings, I convert them to timestamps with lubridate::mdy() first.

###### Sidenotes

1: if you use a YMD format, you won't need to convert strings to timestamps, as they are properly ordered alphabetically. However, a numerical comparison will probably be faster.

2: it will also be faster to replace the character strings with timestamps *in the data frame*; then the conversion would only have to be done once, instead of every time you `filter()`.